# Ionic 4- Receber atualização de variável com BehaviorSubject

Tags: angular, ionic4

Na home tenho uma lista de produtos que no clique abre o modal do produto com um botão para adicionar ao carrinho. Quando adiciona aparece a quantidade junto ao icone. Quero que ao fechar este modal no **app.component** seja atualizado o icone que está no footer. Preciso atualizar este carrinho com o valor do modal que foi fechado sem precisar de refresh.

**servico.ts**

```
 public totalShop: BehaviorSubject<String>;

 constructor() {
    this.totalShop = new BehaviorSubject('0');       
 }

 setTotalShop(val) {    
    this.totalShop.next(val);    
  }

  clearTotalShop() {
    this.totalShop.next('0');
  }

  getTotalShop(){    
    return this.totalShop.asObservable();
  }
```

**modalProduto.ts**

```
 fnShop(){
    quantidade = quantidade +1
    this.servico.setTotalShop(quantidade)
 }
```

**app.component.ts**

```
 quantshop;
 subscription: Subscription;

 ngOnInit(): void {
   this.subscription = this.servicol.getTotalShop().subscribe(val => this.quantshop = val);
   console.log(this.quantshop)
}
```

**app.module**

```
  providers: [servico]
```

**imagem**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não entendi pq utilizou **`this.subscription = this.global.getTotalShop().subscribe(...`** e não **`this.servico.getTotalShop().subscribe(...`** ??

Comment: Erro de digitação, corrigido.

Comment: Alessandro não entendi muito bem! Não bastaria executar uma função ao fechar o modal que emitisse um valor no seu `BehaviorSubject` já que o `app.component` está "ouvindo" este Observable?

Comment: Não entendo pq usar a variável **subscription**, pq o valor retornado **(val)** já está sendo passado para outra variável **`this.quantshop = val`**.

Comment: @MarceloVismari o app.component parece não ouvir

Comment: @LeAndrade foi uma tentativa, mas que também não funcionou.

Comment: O código é asyncrono o valor só vai estar atualizado dentro do subscribe que é o codigo que vai rodar toda vez que o valor mudar.